# warning in react-router dom when user tries to navigate away from the site

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a multistep wizard with each step a react-router route.

Currently if the user navigates away to an external link, they lose all their state.

Is there a catch all in react-router-dom or react-router where I can warn the user and allow them to cancel?

Comment: Could you add a class to each external link so you could attach an event listener that fires a prompt when clicked? You could make an external link component.

Comment: react router dom is now relying on lifecycle of react. if it is navigating away componentWillUnmount might be used to catch that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a component for this. Check out the Prompt component here:
    https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt

Here's the example they use:

```
<Prompt
    when={formIsHalfFilledOut} // <- function that returns boolean
    message="Are you sure you want to leave?"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Blocking Transitions under the history api for React Router.

As per the example on react router history github page:

You can register a simple prompt message that will be shown to the
user before they navigate away from the current page.

```
const unblock = history.block('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')
```

Detailed info at https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#properties